# SQL Server Select additional record based on column value of first record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am looking for a SQL query which will use a value in one record to select a value from an additional record in the same table, returning a value from each of the two records in a single row.

Suppose I have the following table where the ref_id column value will either be null or will contain the id value of another record. The id field is the primary key.

```
 id | name    | ref_id
----+---------+--------
 1  | Joe     | NULL
 2  | Sally   | NULL
 3  | Steve   | 2
 4  | James   | 1
 5  | George  | 2
```

I need a query that will return the following results:

```
 name    | ref_name    
---------+----------
 Joe     | NULL
 Sally   | NULL
 Steve   | Sally
 James   | Joe
 George  | Sally
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

Thank you in advance your your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE( id INT, name VARCHAR(20),ref_id INT)
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES 
( 1,  'Joe',     NULL),
( 2,  'Sally',   NULL),
( 3,  'Steve',   2),
( 4,  'James',   1),
( 5,  'George',  2)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT A.Name , B.Name As Ref_Name
FROM @TABLE A LEFT JOIN @TABLE B
ON A.Ref_ID = B.id
```

**Result**

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║  Name  ║ Ref_Name ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║ Joe    ║ NULL     ║
║ Sally  ║ NULL     ║
║ Steve  ║ Sally    ║
║ James  ║ Joe      ║
║ George ║ Sally    ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you Ali. This works but my understanding is I should not use a join for performance reasons. Is this not the case or is there a way to accomplish this without a join?

Comment: I think join is the most efficient way of accomplishing this, seriously cant really think of any other way.

Comment: I tried treating it like a recursive table using CTE and that didn't seem like it was a good approach. I will stick with this very simple, and quite embarrassing, solution. Thank you!